# remove weight by part of the mesh in weightpaint mode

Tags: weight-painting

I have got a mesh made of multiple part (the mesh is a dog, each limb is a separate part) I am trying to paint the weight of the back leg but I have trouble doing so because that leg intersect the body. Is there a way to remove the weight painted on the body while keeping it on the leg (something similar to select a mesh island with "L" in edit mode)

here is my object:
[image]
as you can see the leg intersect the body
[image]

as you can see the upper bone of the leg has a bit of weight on the body
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the part you want in edit mode: select and use <kbd>H</kbd>.

Then go in vertex paint mode and click on the *'vertex selection'* button. The unwanted part will be hidden.

Then select all the remaining vertices using <kbd>A</kbd> to paint on them.

[image]

Comment: I have made my rigging and weight paint in 2.79 is it possible to import it in 2.8 to continue editing it as in your exemple (I have already try to import it in 2.8 as an fbx and obj but it doesn't work

Comment: It works exactly the same way in 2.79. Simply the vertex selection button is usually below the 3D view. So working in 2.8 is not mandatory.